# Assigning a variable of reference type "slice" to another variable, why don't they change simultaneously?

Tags: go, reference-type

```
anotherSlice := theSlice
anotherSlice = append(anotherSlice, newEle)
fmt.Println(len(anotherSlice) == len(theSlice))
```

This snippet will output `false`. Why?

And here are some other experiments:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    theSlice := []int{3,3,2,5,12,43}
    anotherSlice := theSlice
    fmt.Println(anotherSlice[3], theSlice[3])
    anotherSlice[3] = anotherSlice[3]+2
    fmt.Println(anotherSlice[3], theSlice[3])
    anotherSlice = append(anotherSlice[:3], anotherSlice[4:]...)
    fmt.Println(len(anotherSlice),len(theSlice))
}
```

The output is like below:

```
5 5
7 7
5 6

Program exited.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever appended slice `anotherSlice` has no capacity for the new element, `append` function creates new slice and returns it. Since then the slices `anotherSlice` and `theSlice` are different - they are backed by separate arrays.

Reslicing slice with a shorter length `anotherSlice[:3]` has no impact on the original capacity of the slice.

The following line:

```
anotherSlice = append(anotherSlice[:3], anotherSlice[4:]...)
```

cuts out fourth (index 3) element. Because `anotherSlice[:3]` has capacity to hold all elements of `anotherSlice[4:]` no new allocation happens and therefore both slices are modified.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)   

func main() {
        x := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
        fmt.Println(cap(x[:3]) >= len(x[:3])+len(x[4:]))
        y := append(x[:3], x[4:]...)
        fmt.Println(x, y)
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/jiX4tyEcXz)

- [Go Slices](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)
- [Capacity function](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#cap)
- [Slice tricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks)

Comment: I tried something else to shrink the length, the process is updated in the post. Is that because after shrinking, `anotherSlice` has also shrinked capacity to 5?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to why the length of one slice doesn't follow the change to another slice's length change is not related to the underlying storage potentially being copied and/or modified.

In Go, it is important to remember what a slice is.  It is a struct with a length field, a capacity field, and a pointer to an array.  Some operations
change the length field.  Some change the capacity field.  Some change the data stored in the underlying array.

If one doesn't grasp how a slice is implemented in the language, there will be all sorts of confusion and bugs and wasted opportunities.  Once one becomes comfortable with how a slice is implemented, they are very easy to use and the fact that the compiler understands the structure of the slice, some very elegant and easily read code can be written.